# Getting a method Name from the Xml element name in the metadata

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, metadata

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "SalesStageId", Form = XmlSchemaForm.None)]
public EntityIdentifier OpportunitySalesStageId { get; set; }
```

Here above the `ElementName` is `"SalesStageId"` while the method name is `"OpportunitySalesStageId"`.

Is there any way to find out the method name from the element name through an object of the class containing the above method.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the method name? (Inside another class, or perhaps an external library?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use reflection to get a type's properties with [`Type.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx)
2. Then you can search each `PropertyInfo` for the custom attribute `XmlElementAttribute` with [`PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx)
3. If the attribute was found (i.e. not null) you can then simply query its contents to see if it matches.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the remaining properties

**Example Program:**

(optimized with LINQ and extension methods)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string propName = FindPropertyNameByXmlElementAttributeElementName(typeof (MyClass), "Foo");

            Console.WriteLine(propName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static string FindPropertyNameByXmlElementAttributeElementName(Type type, string elementName)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = 
                type.GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(
                        prop => prop.HasAttributeWithValue<XmlElementAttribute>(
                                a => a.ElementName == elementName
                            )
                    );
            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                return "NOT FOUND";
            }
            return propertyInfo.Name;
        }
    }

    public static class PropertyInfoExtensions
    {
        public static bool HasAttributeWithValue<TAttribute>(this PropertyInfo pi, Func<TAttribute, bool> hasValue)
        {
            TAttribute attribute = 
                (TAttribute)pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault();
            if (attribute == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return hasValue(attribute);
        }
    }
    class MyClass
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Foo", Form = XmlSchemaForm.None)]
        public string Rumplestiltskin { get; set; }
    }
}
```